# Multiple conditions in if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

No matter what number is generated here I always get the first option (penguins).  I can't seem to see any problem with my code, anyone else see what's wrong?

```
{
    srand(time(0));
    prand = (rand() % 20);
    if (prand == 1,5,9,10,14,15,19,20){
        entity = "penguins";
        srand(time(0));
        pquantity = (rand() % 8) + 2;
    }
    else if (prand == 2,6,11,16,18){
        entity = "troll";
        pquantity = 1;
    }
    else if (prand == 3,7,12,17){
        entity = "goblin";
        pquantity = 1;
    }
    else if (prand == 4,8,13){
        entity = "wizard";
        pquantity = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is this? C maybe? Please add a suitable language tag (there's an edit link below your question)

Comment: Is `1,5,9,10,14,15,19,20` a string or an array of multiple values?

Comment: If it's C or C++, then you're experiencing the result of the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). (The first `if` becomes the equivalent of `if(20)`)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Do you mean the equivalent of `if (prand == 20)`?

Comment: @Code-Guru - no, the last expression in that sequence is `20`. That's why that `if` always evaluates as true.

Comment: Actually `prand` will never equal to 20... And where is 0? ;)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Oh right... `==` has higher precedence than `,`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code fragment `prand == 1,5,9,10,14,15,19,20` is a *sequence of expressions* (the `,` is usually know as the *comma operator*), where the result of the *first* (or *last* — depending on language) expression *only* is used as a condition for the `if` statement. The remaining expressions are evaluated and their value is forgotten (please note this may lead to serious side effects in more complex situations.)

It's not very clear what language you are using, but in, say, C# you could use a [switch statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/06tc147t.aspx) to achieve what you want:

```
switch (prand)
{
    // first set of options
    case 1:
    case 5:
    …
    case 20:
        // your code here
        break;

    // second set of options
    case 2:
    case 6: 
    …
    case 18:
        // your code here
        break;

    default:
        // all other options not listed above
        break;
}
```

Most languages have such a statement. See this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement) for a general description.

Comment: If it's C or C++, then the result of the *last* expression is used, which is why that `if` is always entered.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Right, thanks. Clarified my answer to be a bit more language-neutral.

Comment: If the code is in C or C++ the the result of the *last* expression is what counts. Try `int i = 1; if(i == 1,0) { cout << "1,0!" << endl; } if(i == 2,99) { cout << "2,99!" << endl; }`

Comment: Even in C++, I'd use a `switch` here, rather than a sequence of `if`.

Answer (score 3):

You're misusing the comma operator.  The expression in the first
if is:

```
if ( (prand == 1), (5), (9), (10), (14), (15), (19), (20) )
```

with each of the commas a comma operator.  The definition of
a comma operator is to evaluate the first expression (for
possible side effects), then evaluate the second; the value of
the expression is the value of the second expression.  So your
if becomes the exact equivalent of:

```
if ( 20 )
```

And `20` is implicitly converted to a `bool`, resulting in
`true`.

Your compiler should have warned you about this.  Something to
the effect of a useless expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (prand == 1,5,9,10,14,15,19,20)
```

Although this is valid C++ and will compile, it does not do what you expect. You need to compare the variable to each value in turn:

```
if (prand == 1 || prand == 5 || prand == 9 || prand == 10 || prand == 14 || prand == 15 || prand == 19 || prand == 20)
```

This is because `==` is a binary operator which takes two values of compatible types.

In this situation, a switch...case statement is preferred as @Ondrej has explained.

I can think of at least two alternative ways to simulating a dice roll (which it appears you are trying to do:

1. Use consecutive values for each option:

   ```
   if (prand >= 1 && prand <= 8) {
       // ...
   } else if (prand >= 9 && prand <= 13) {
       // ...
   } else if (prand >= 14 && prand <= 17) {
       // ...
   } else if (prand >= 18 && prand <= 20) {
       // ...
   } else {
       // Print an error message
   }
   ```
2. Store the different possibilities in a `std::list<std::set<int>>`. Then you can iterate over the sets in the list and use the `std::set.contains()` method to check if the current set contains the value. This has the advantage of scalability. For example, it makes it easier to code the choices for 1d100 or other dice rolls with a large number of possible values.

Comment: Nice solution. But `prand` will never equal to 20, but it can be 0. So You will have an error message. Sooner or later...

Comment: @TrueY Good point. I didn't look at the intialization of `prand` since that wasn't the central part of the OP's question. Of course that is easy enough to fix: `int prand = (rand() % 20) + 1;`

Answer (score 1):

If it is "C" then You are testing the result of a comma operator. So the result of `prand == 1,5,9,10,14,15,19,20`, is the last element (BTW the first element is `prand == 1`). It is `20` which is always true.

I would suggest to build an array and check its elements...

```
enum Being_t {BEING_PENGUIN, BEING_TROLL, BEING_GOBLIN, BEING_WIZARD};
enum Being_t arr[20] = {BEING_PENGUIN, BEING_TROLL, BEING_GOBLIN, BEING_WIZARD,
    BEING_PENGUIN, BEING_TROLL, BEING_GOBLIN, BEING_WIZARD, ...};
```

Then You can use a switch

```
srand(time(0));
prand = (rand() % 20);
switch (arr[prand]) {
case BEING_PENGUIN:
    ...
    break;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use or's or switch statements. For example, with if

```
if (prand == 1 || prand == 5 || prand == 9 || prand == 10 || prand == 14|| prand == 15|| prand == 19|| prand == 20)
{
        // your code here
}
```

and with switch

```
switch (prand)
{
    case 1:
    {

        // your code here

        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {

        // your code here

        break;
    }
    case 9:
    {

        // your code here

        break;
    }
    case 10:
    {

        // your code here

        break;
    }
    case 14:
    {

        // your code here

        break;
    }
    case 15:
    {

        // your code here

        break;
    }
    case 19:
    {

        // your code here

        break;
    }
    case 20:
    {

        // your code here

        break;
    }
}
```