# How do I make multiple if statements inside one another taking user input in C++?

Tags: c++, if-statement, user-input

so I am new to programming, especially with C++ and I am trying to write a bank program, where I am currently trying to make the person an "account" asking them if they want to make a Basic, Premium, or Elite account, and then confirming the account with a yes or no answer from the user. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string mystr;
    cout << "Hello there, which account would you like to start today? Basic, Premium or Elite? ";
    getline(cin, mystr);

    string yn_answer;
    if (mystr == "Elite") {
        cout << "You have chosen the Elite account option. Is this correct? (y/n): ";
        getline(cin, yn_answer);
        if (yn_answer == "y")
            cout << "Great, setting up account... \n";
        cout << "25% complete. \n";
        cout << "50% complete. \n";
        cout << "75% complete. \n";
        cout << "100% complete. \n";
        cout << "Process complete. \n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "I'm sorry for the inconvenience, please restart the program. Thanks! ";
    }

    if (mystr == "Premium") {
        cout << "Hello, Premium";
    }

    if (mystr == "Basic") {
        cout << "Hello, Basic";
    }

    if (mystr != "Basic", "Elite", "Premium") {
        cout << "I'm sorry, you did not choose one of the following options above. Please try again.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Currently I only have the first one, Elite, done and the Basic and Premium will be copied over when I can figure out how to get it to work. However, when I try to run this by typing Elite in as the user input I get the character output, "I'm sorry, you did not choose one of the following options above. Please try again.", from the last line trying to check if the user entered in something other than Elite, Basic, or Premium.

If I type in something other than the three options, I should get "I'm sorry, you did not choose one of the following options above. Please try again". However, I get the first "error" message that is supposed to be checking for the user confirming the account type as well as the actual error message I am supposed to be getting.

I'm very new to programming, and I don't really know how to explain these things. If you don't understand something I'm trying to do, please let me know and I'll try to explain it better. Also, is there a way that I can do this better, or is there a way to fix what I am doing here? Thanks.

*Also, I've heard that using namespace for std isn't a good practice to do, but I'm currently using an online compiler and that was how it was originally and I don't want to change things around now after working on this and mess it up more than it already is. I've been working on this for a while and have been fixing it up until this point where I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: If you are serious about learning C++ you will need to get and install your own compiler, and use its editor (or an accompanying editor) that is capable of automatically indenting your code in a logical, consistent manner. Without logical indentation the shown code is mostly unreadable, and incomprehensible. Writing readable code is an important part of being a skilled C++ developer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yeah, I know. I have Codeblocks on my PC, however it's broken atm and I don't think that my laptop (which I'm using currently) would be able to run it. Also, it doesn't help that I'm new to stack overflow and wasn't really sure how to enter the code into the code box.

Comment: Place three backticks, `, before and after the code and your indentation will be maintained. The rendering engine usually figures the rest out from the language tags or some deep magic I'm not privy to.

Comment: Code::blocks doesn't take much in the way of computing power. Whatever compiler it's using might be slow, but will be able to handle any program a beginner can be expected to write. If for some reason you still can't get things to go, look at [online gdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) so you can at least get debugger support. Learning to code with out a debugger available is for suckers.

Comment: @user4581301 Alright, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple conditions in if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281125/multiple-conditions-in-if-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string mystr;
cout << "Hello there, which account would you like to start today? Basic, Premium or Elite? ";
cin >> mystr;

string yn_answer;
if (mystr == "Elite")
{
    cout << "You have chosen the Elite account option. Is this correct? (y/n): ";
    cin >> yn_answer;
    if (yn_answer == "y")
    {
        cout << "Great, setting up account... \n";
        cout << "25% complete. \n";
        cout << "50% complete. \n";
        cout << "75% complete. \n";
        cout << "100% complete. \n";
        cout << "Process complete. \n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "I'm sorry for the inconvenience, please restart the program. Thanks! ";
    }

    return 0;
}
else if (mystr == "Premium")
{
    cout << "You have chosen the Elite account";
}
else if (mystr == "Basic")
{
    cout << "You have chosen the Basic account";
}
else
{
    cout << "This isn't a choice, restart the program";
}
```

tested, it should be working, I've seen you forgot a { at if (yn_answer == "y") and you added a } at the end, normaly when you start it you end it and when you end, you start it, but it must've been an error, don't worry and I prefer using a simple cin instead of getline. cin's always working. Plus, your 3 if at the end aren't useful, because mystr cannot be equal to something else to Elite, because to be at this point in the program mystr need to be equal to Elite (The first if statement).

If you want advice, your next step in learning C++ could be while loop, so not need anymore to restart the program, for example

```
bool restart = true;
string mystr;

while (restart)
{
    cout << "Do you want to restart ? (y/n)";
    cin >> mystr;

    if (mystr == "y")
    {
        cout << "Nice !\n";
    }
    else
    {
        restart = false;
    }
}
```

If you say n, it will restart the loop

Comment: is there somewhere I can contact you? I've ran into a problem that I have no idea how to fix, and no one else seems to be of any help here.. idk what to do.

Comment: Discord Dolotboy#5172